One table has relation with either one of the three table Laravel
I have animals table which has relation with rats,cats and dogs.
Animal Table



ID
Date of Birth
Gender




1
23-10-2022
Male


2
23-11-2022
Female


3
13-10-2022
Male


4
14-11-2022
Female


5
01-10-2022
Male


6
02-11-2022
Female



Rats Table



ID
Date of Weaned
Animal ID
Col1
Col2




1
12-11-2022
1
3
5


2
12-12-2022
2
4
6



Cats Table



ID
Date of Weaned
Animal ID
C1
C2




1
12-01-2023
3
st1
rt1


2
12-01-2023
4
st2
rt2



Dogs Table



ID
Date of Weaned
Animal ID
P1
P2




1
01-01-2023
5
p1
p3


2
02-01-2023
6
p2
p4



How to fetch all the Animals sorted by weaned date?
My Modal looks like
class Animal extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'date_of_birth',
        'gender'
    ];
    
    public function rats() 
    {
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Weaning');
        return $this->hasOne(Rats::class,'animal_id','id');
    }
public function cats() 
    {
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Weaning');
        return $this->hasOne(Cats::class,'animal_id','id');
    }
public function dogs() 
    {
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Weaning');
        return $this->hasOne(Dogs::class,'animal_id','id');
    }
}

Is my Relation correct?

This structure seems sub-optimal to me, at least for the data shown. I'd have a single animals table with a type value of rat/cat/dog.

I edited the table

In your data structure you have a 1-1 relationship with each type of animal. My guess is that animals have some columns that are specific to one type of animal, and columns that every animal model contains. Logically the "shared" fields would be in your animals table.  and the specific columns in your "cats" table for example. This would make queries simple. There is also the option of polymorphic relationships. but i think that would be overkill in this case imho
